# Internal SATA HDD fails with sdb I/O error when connected as external

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I am trying to attach the internal SATA HDD from my Thinkpad T420, to new laptop, using a SATA connector to USB port. But it fails with read error.

However it works fine when placed back into the old laptop. The HDD is having 4 partitions, dual boot, running Ubuntu(/ and home) as primary OS and Windows(C: and D:) when required.

I tried connecting it as external to different kind of OS'es (Windows, Linux, Mac) but all fail.

How to fix this ? I wish to transfer data from old HDD without going through the pain of CIFS/NFS share or SCP on LAN

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is the USB adapter which is either malfunctioning or incompatible?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a case of an under-powered drive if it's not getting enough power through the SATA to USB cable. I'd try with an enclosure with external power or a dock station.

I'd also recommend trying the drive internally and see if it works this way.

Checking the drive's health can also give you more details about its condition and why it is not recognized. Running a diagnostic tool from the manufacturer can give you that information. Checking the raw values of the S.M.A.R.T. status is also a good thing.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: I see this as an answer, not a comment, the first sentence is a question and should be edited, the rest is an answer.

Comment: The drive is perfectly healthy. As I mentioned, it works fine internally. Only connecting it externally fails. I tried with extra power source too but no avail :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your adapter is broken?

If you are sure that disk is healthy you should use better adapter or connect disk directly to SATA.

Comment: I was of the same opinion, hence tried 2 different adapters. Both work well with other disks which I have, but not this one.  I didn't get the comment about directly to SATA ?

Comment: Connecting directly to SATA is possible only if you have second SATA drive port in your new laptop. If you cannot do that the easiest option is to copy files by SSH.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)